# Keeping constants inside namespace

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to keep my defined constants just inside the scope of my Wordpress plugin as I feel that a plugin should not be filling up the global namespace unless necessary.

I have a structure like:

```
namespace pluginname;
namespace pluginname\setup;
namespace pluginname\helpers;

etc...
```

I tried doing:

```
define('pluginname\var', 'foo');
```

and then in the child namespaces doing:

```
use pluginname;
```

But this does not bring the constant into scope.  Is this the right approach but wrong syntax or vice versa?

Should I create a static definition class instead?  I am coming from .NET background and getting a little confused with PHP implementation of namespaces and scoping.

What is the preferred approach?

Comment: Everything in PHP is very well documented. There is a FAQ: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.nofuncconstantuse and http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.innamespace

Comment: Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.innamespace): `Inside a single-quoted string, the backslash escape sequence is much safer to use, but it is still recommended practice to escape backslashes in all strings as a best practice.`

Comment: @Marc I read it but it's not clear to me.  Is using constant from another namespace only supported in 5.6? Do I have to extend a class that has protected properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `use` to import constants in namespaces ([FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.nofuncconstantuse)).

Here is an example to understand, how you could do it:

```
namespace pluginname { // pluginname
    define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\TEST', 'This my test constant.'.PHP_EOL);
    echo TEST;
}

namespace pluginname\setup { // pluginname\setup
    echo \pluginname\TEST;
}

namespace pluginname\helpers { // pluginname\helpers
    echo \pluginname\TEST;
}

namespace { // global
    echo pluginname\TEST;
    echo TEST;
}
```

This would print:

```
This my test constant.
This my test constant.
This my test constant.
This my test constant.
TEST
```

Comment: OK I understand.  So there is no way to bring the constant into scope you have to always use the fully qualified name.  So I guess for long paths you would do `use pluginname\a\long\obscure\path as p` then `p\foo` to save typing it out every time?  I am just used to being able to bring things into scope so it confused me as I figured there would be a way.

Comment: Yeah, importing will require 5.6 `use const My\Full\CONSTANT;`http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php but you can do it with variables, so you have to use the whole namespace name only once